# What am i doing wrong in this parallax effect using framer motion?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am trying to achieve a parallax effect using framer motion.

I want the background image in the middle section to stay still but ***its keep covering up the content*** from the above div as i scroll.

I have been googling for 3 hours now and trying different approaches but its not working.

Here is the effect i want https://codepen.io/cgrkzlkn/pen/yLjzPmp but this is using vanilla javascript.

Here is my code. Can someone help

```
import { useScroll, useTransform, motion } from "framer-motion";
const Landing = () => {
  const ref = useRef() as MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: ref,
    offset: ["end end", "end start"],
  });
  const backgroundY = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ["0%", "-100%"]);

  return (
   <>
     <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <motion.div
    ref={ref}
    style={{ y: backgroundY }}
    className={styles.parallaxItem}
  >
    <h2 className={styles.testing}>Div 1</h2>
  </motion.div>
  <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
   </>
  )
}
```

here is the css

```
.parallaxItem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1663305411753-4c305e177ff3?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NjM5NDA4ODE&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```